# Vertically overflow hidden dynamic height DIVs, needs to move to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I vertically overflow hidden dynamic height child DIVs can move to the right?

```css
.parent {
  height: 510px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden
}

.child {
  width: 49px;
  /* **Note**: Height cannot be hardcoded since it changes based on the data from response */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child1</div>
  <div class="child">child2</div>
  <div class="child">child3</div>
  <div class="child">child4</div>
  <div class="child">child5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on what you would like to do?

Comment: I cannot even begin to decipher what you are trying to say. Please explain, in clear terms, what you need that code to do.

Comment: Thanks Sagar for your reply!
Parent DIV container is part of my web page. In it, I have 5 child DIV containers and its height varies based on the data. For eg: Child1 height is 100px, Child2 height is 200px, Child3 height is 150px,...

Comment: Child4 height is 250px,Child5 height is 175px,...

So in Child1 and 2 alone fit in the parent due to overflow:hidden.

In this case, rest three child 3,4&5 DIVs are hidden so to make it visible I want to move those containers to right.

Can you please help to achieve this or suggest me if you have any better solution?

Comment: @user3721995 please edit your question and include the explanation instead of posting it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible. If it is then I do not know of that solution. 
There are 2 approaches to your desired solution that I can currently think of.

1>  Increase parent div's `width` size enough to contain all childs column-wise. 
2> Add overflow scroll effect with limited height to all childs and increase overflow height of the parent.

Also on the side note, I see that your parent's width is 100px while the child is 49. I believe you would like to have at least 2 rows side-by-side in the parent. To do that do add `float` property into the child css

```
.parent {
   text-align: center;
   height: 510px;
   width: 100px;
   overflow-y: hidden
}

.child {
   width: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Downvoters please do mention the reason so that I could improve and refrain from doing the same mistakes in future

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I have tried with float left but creates blank space issues between child containers. May be Javascript or jQuery can help us.

Comment: My requirement is, the first vertical column should be populated completely then populate the next vertical column.

Comment: My requirement is, the first vertical column should be populated completely then populate the second vertical column. So that white blank space in the first column is not allowed.

Comment: Float:left is at most equivalent to display:inline-blank for this scenario.

Comment: @Dineshkumar I have modified the answer slightly as per your last requirements

Comment: I have tried this solution already but no luck. It creates blank space issue due to the dynamic height of child DIV containers.

Comment: @Dineshkumar there's also `white-space: no-wrap` property if you are willing to break words in the middle.

Comment: No luck. I think we cannot achieve this without JS or jQuery.

Comment: @Dineshkumar even that will not be able to help you out

Comment: Eventually, I have achieved it using CSS + AngularJS script :)

Comment: @Dineshkumar please do post ur answer explaining what and how you achieved it

Comment: I have achieved by using scroll position, the height of the page, the height of each DIV containers. Based on these values derived a calculation when collapse and expand the containers. Its purely achieved using JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Begin HTML -->    
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child" id="firstCategory">child1</div>
      <div class="child" id="sceondCategory">child2</div>
      <div class="child" id="thirdCategory">child3</div>
      <div class="child" id="fourthCategory">child4</div>
    </div>
<!-- End HTML -->    
<!-- Begin CSS -->    
    .handle-first-right-category{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50.5%;    
        /* bottom: 65.5%; Note: To handle the calculation its better to hard code in px instead of using % */
        top: 0px;
    }

    .handle-second-right-category{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50.5%;
    }

    .handle-third-right-category{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50.5%;
    }
    <!-- End CSS -->    
<!-- Begin angular js -->    
    var firstCategory = angular.element('#firstCategory'); 
    var secondCategory = angular.element('#secondCategory');
    var thirdCategory = angular.element('#thirdCategory';
    var fourthCategory = angular.element('#fourthCategory';

                if(firstCategory && secondCategory && 
                        (firstCategory.offsetHeight + secondCategory.offsetHeight > 510)){
                    //Move the 2nd, 3rd & 4th categories to right
                    secondCategory.classList.add('handle-first-right-category');
                    if (thirdCategory) {
                        thirdCategory.classList.add('handle-second-right-category');
                        thirdCategory.style.top = secondCategory.offsetHeight + 5 + "px";
                    }
                    if (fourthCategory){
                        fourthCategory.classList.add('handle-third-right-category');
                        fourthCategory.style.top = secondCategory.offsetHeight + thirdCategory.offsetHeight + 10 +  "px";
                    }   
                }
                else if(firstCategory && secondCategory && thirdCategory && 
                        (firstCategory.offsetHeight + secondCategory.offsetHeight + thirdCategory.offsetHeight > 510)){
                    //Move the 3rd & 4th categories to right
                    thirdCategory.classList.add('handle-first-right-category');
                    if (fourthCategory){
                        fourthCategory.classList.add('handle-second-right-category');
                        fourthCategory.style.top = thirdCategory.offsetHeight + 5 +  "px";
                    }   
                }
                else if(firstCategory && secondCategory && thirdCategory && fourthCategory && 
                        (firstCategory.offsetHeight + secondCategory.offsetHeight + thirdCategory.offsetHeight + fourthCategory.offsetHeight > 510)){
                    //Move the 4th category to right
                    fourthCategory.classList.add('handle-first-right-category');
                }
<!-- End angular js -->
```